# Cross WCF services reference

Tags: wcf, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have a WCF service, called `A` which implements `IA`. This server uses some classes that are defined in a common class (in a `common dll` referenced by the `A service dll`). I have another WCF service, called `B` which implements `IB`.

Now, `A` and `B` have service reference to each other. This worked fine. But now, when I try to update `IB` I have a problem. I get a custom tool error failing to generate the code for the service reference. Unchecking the `“Reuse types in referenced assemblies”` solves this issue, but then I have to cast each type to itself (actually).

I created a separate project, in A solution, that has reference to `B` service. Now, I am able to add service reference, but I get ambiguous error for all types that are defined in the `common dll`. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: what error(s) exactly? which VS version? add code examples of the casts you deem neccessary. consider adding paragraphs to the Q, its a bit WOT

Comment: It is a circular dependency problem. Basically a design flaw. You should change your approach.